# Group by on already grouped and aggregated data - Postgresql 9.3 and above

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Table "A" Content :

```
      IP       | Port
----------------+-------
10.211.240.300 | 10
10.211.240.300 | 10
10.211.240.300 | 20
10.211.240.300 | 20
10.211.240.300 | 20
10.211.240.300 | 20
10.211.240.300 | 30
10.211.240.300 | 30
10.211.240.300 | 30
10.211.240.200 | 10
10.211.240.200 | 10
10.211.240.200 | 10
10.211.240.200 | 20
10.211.240.200 | 20
10.211.240.200 | 20
10.211.240.200 | 20
10.211.240.200 | 30
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 10
10.211.240.100 | 20
10.211.240.100 | 20
10.211.240.100 | 20
10.211.240.100 | 30
10.211.240.100 | 30
10.211.240.100 | 30
10.211.240.100 | 30
10.211.240.100 | 30
```

I need to order the IP addresses with its count and also need ordered count for its ports, so the expected outcome for above data is :

```
       IP      | Port    | PortCount  | TotalCount
----------------------------------------------
 10.211.240.100 | 10      |  08        | 16
 10.211.240.100 | 30      |  05        | 16
 10.211.240.100 | 20      |  03        | 16
 10.211.240.300 | 30      |  04        | 09
 10.211.240.300 | 20      |  03        | 09
 10.211.240.300 | 10      |  02        | 09
 10.211.240.200 | 20      |  04        | 08
 10.211.240.200 | 10      |  03        | 08
 10.211.240.200 | 30      |  01        | 08
```

Can some one please help me with postgres relational query for the same??

Comment: your data sample is not clear, could you please format it readable?..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.IP, A.PORT, T2.PORT_COUNT, COUNT(*) 
FROM A JOIN (
             SELECT T1.IP, COUNT(T1.PORT) AS PORT_COUNT
             FROM A AS T1
             GROUP BY T1.IP  
            ) AS T2
            ON A.IP =  T2.IP
GROUP BY A.IP, A.PORT
```

Online DB where I tested this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a78/6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgresql then please use query :-

```
SELECT a.IP, a.PORT,total_count.total,COUNT(*)
FROM a
JOIN (
         SELECT b.IP, COUNT(b.PORT) AS total
         FROM a AS b
         GROUP BY b.IP  
        ) AS total_count
        ON a.IP =  total_count.IP
GROUP BY a.IP, a.PORT,total_count.total
ORDER BY a.ip
```

Comment: I need some further help.. I only need top 2 ports and rest of the ports should be aggregated as say "Others"..  so expcted output is :     IP      | Port    | PortCount  | TotalCount

 10.211.240.100 | 10      |  08        | 16
 10.211.240.100 | Other     |  05        | 16
 10.211.240.100 | 20      |  03        | 16
 10.211.240.300 | Other      |  04        | 09
 10.211.240.300 | 20      |  03        | 09
 10.211.240.300 | 10      |  02        | 09
 10.211.240.200 | 20      |  04        | 08
 10.211.240.200 | 10      |  03        | 08
 10.211.240.200 | Other      |  01        | 08

Comment: Thanks for the help..  The aim is to get Top 5 IP Addresses and then on top of it return the TOP 2 port counts as it is and aggregation of rest of the ports as "Other"

Comment: @DivyeshKateliya still you are facing any problem?

Comment: Yes @Amit.. Any help??